# ASP.NET MVC: Action Method and automatically binding to an array of values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a piece of javascript that posts to an action method, and with it some data.
This data is in the form:

```
pageID  1
photos[1]   2
photos[2]   1
```

My Action Method looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult PosImage(IEnumerable<int> photos, int pageID)
```

Naturally, pageID comes through in the form data, but photos is always null.

Is it possible for ASP.MVC to bind like this?

The JS that handles the post looks as follows:

```
var ids = { 'photos': {}, 'pageID': SitePhotos.site_id };
    $('#stone-photo-sortable li').each(function (i) {
        i++;
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
        ids.photos[id] = i;
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/backend/site/posimage/?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime(),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ids,
        beforeSend: function () { },
        complete: function () { },
        success: function (html) {
            if (html.worked == 1) {
                Notify.add('success', 'New Positions saved to the database..');
            } else {
                Notify.add('failure', 'Couldn\'t save positions.');
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent done it from javascript, but your post data should actually be like this:

```
photos: 1
photos: 2
photos: 3
```

You probably need to use a different $.ajax overload inorder to pass post data with duplicate key names.

**edit** seems like all you have to do is to set [traditional](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) flag to true.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this would work better for you if you turn the photos object around and making it into an array instead like this:

```
var ids = { 'photos': [], 'pageID': SitePhotos.site_id };
    $('#stone-photo-sortable li').each(function (i) {
        ids.photos[i] = $(this).attr('rel');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergio, this can be fixed very easy.

`IEnumerable<int> photos` will work, but your array should always start at `0`! not at `1`

make it start at `0` and MVC will parse it into your `IEnumerable`

read more about it here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx